# how can i enable ionic notification in background?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

The notification not working when i closed my app so i need to open my app to receive all notification.

Is there any plugin for that? i tried to using background-mode but my app not work

app.components.ts

```
   import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';

   constructor(private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode, platform: 
    Platform,statusBar: StatusBar,splashScreen: SplashScreen,
     private storage: Storage) {

    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at Firebase Cloud Messaging, this works well with Ionic

Answer (score 0):

please read the official documentation a bit more. Probably you will have to install and use the Push plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/.

Obviously you need some back-end service on your server that pushes messages to any client.